# string accept error name accept part getting skipped

Tags: arrays

This is the my code and the problem is using array i am taking names and their marks input and want to print then serially but the name accepting part is not working it is taking number inputs but not the names

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ST_test 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        int i;
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        String a[]= new String[5];
        int num[]= new int[5];
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            
            System.out.println("position mrks"+i);
            num[i]=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("position name "+i);
            a[i]=sc.nextLine();

        }
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(" "+a[i]+" ");
            System.out.print(" "+num[i]+" ");

       }

     }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 0):

I used to encounter this error early on in my Java journey. The problem is with the Scanner class, probably a bug.

The solution that I used was to create 2 scanner class objects. One for the numeric values and the other for String values. Here is the modified code:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ST_test 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    int i;
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in); // new scanner object for Strings
    String a[]= new String[5];
    int num[]= new int[5];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        
        System.out.println("position mrks"+i);
        num[i]=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("position name "+i);
        a[i]=sc1.nextLine();

    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(" "+a[i]+" ");
        System.out.print(" "+num[i]+" ");

   }

 }
 }
```

While this helps, it would be better to switch to BufferedReader and BufferedWriter class :)